# Jodit File Browser

Tags: jodit

How Can I view File path using jodit Finder pro , I want to show one file only once I open the view that has the the filebrowser

i tried this code but it does not work, can any one help?

```
function openFb() {
        const fb = new Jodit.modules.FileBrowser({
            uploader: {
                url: 'https://xdsoft.net/jodit/finder/?action=fileUpload'
            },
            ajax: {
                url: 'https://xdsoft.net/jodit/finder/'
            }
        });

        fb.open("C:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/document");
    }
```